# Configure Group Policy

Tags: c#, .net-2.0, group-policy

I'm a programmer, which to write my first program, i already write it... and now I'm providing user interface and the side things which i wish to do automatically instead of making user to do all of them manually...

The problem i have is to Configure Group Policy, i find some of codes but I'm unable to understand them...

what i now looking for is any class library or code i can use them to do these changes...

http://www.watchdirectory.net/wdhelp/plugins/wdopAuditInfoConf.html

...through C#

please if you reference to a code, provide a sample usage, because i also find many codes, which i didn't know how to use, and mostly i didn't know what kinda value i should pass to them... :|

Thank you,
Hassan F.

Comment: i know how to google a matter, but i dunno how to find contact of people which know the codes that i find in google... to clearing the code for me :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Group Policy` assembly references or use registry for Configuring Group Policy.
for more information try this:
[How to apply Windows group policy using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266797/how-to-apply-windows-group-policy-using-net)

Comment: man, like i know how to use it... 

i also see this link before, but the problem is... i dunno event where it placed in registery , or what are the other inpute :(