# C#, how to Config a GPO?

Tags: c#, configuration, group-policy, gpo

the code below successfully create a GPO, but it is useless because it need to be :

1) linked to an OU

2) configured by values

3) add security filtering

```
using Microsoft.GroupPolicy;

private void ManipulateGPO(){
    GPDomain domain = new GPDomain("sh.dom");
    Gpo gpo_background = domain.CreateGpo("testingGPO");
}
```

any help will be appreciated :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to apply Windows group policy using .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266797/how-to-apply-windows-group-policy-using-net)

Comment: @Vanna i need c# code :(

Comment: @JNYRanger  i need c# code :(

Comment: @Vanna if i cant config a gpo using gpmc then what is the point creating it ??