# Windows 10 c# Disable edge swipes in fullscreen mode

Tags: c#, windows, swipe

we have a desktop application written in C# and touch gestures in full screen mode should not work. I've reviewed a few sample code, unfortunately I did not succeed. It needs to be compatible with Windows 10 and Windows 8. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

From your description, it seems that you want to disable the Windows Edge-Swipe using C# under the full screen mode, right? If that is the case, please refer to the following steps to disable the Edge_Swipe.

To detect whether application in Full screen mode.

If you Desktop application is Universal apps, you could refer to [this article](https://marcominerva.wordpress.com/2015/07/09/full-screen-mode-in-windows-10-universal-apps/), then using the [ApplicationView.IsFullScreen Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.isfullscreen#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_IsFullScreen) or [ApplicationView.IsFullScreenMode Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.viewmanagement.applicationview.isfullscreenmode#Windows_UI_ViewManagement_ApplicationView_IsFullScreenMode) to check whether it is in Full screen mode.

Besides, you could check [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9384/Full-Screen-Mode-in-C) and [Detecting fullscreen mode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f76fd820-2b35-4c00-9fb8-202c16da99ae/detecting-fullscreen-mode?forum=csharpgeneral).

There are two method to enable/disable the Windows Edge-Swipe: Group Policy and Registry.

To disable the Windows Edge-Swipe via Group Policy.

we could navigate to **Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Edge UI** for system-wide, or **User Configuration>Administrative Templates>Windows Components>Edge UI** for current user. Then, Edit and Disable "**Allow edge swipe**". More information, please click [Windows 10 Edge-Swipe](https://infocuscorp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002247666-Windows-10-Edge-Swipe),

To disable the Windows edge-swipe via the Registry.

We could open registry editor, and navigate to "**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\EdgeUI**", then, set the **AllowEdgeSwipe** value ((delete) = Enable; 0 = Disable). More detail information, please check [How to disable touchscreen edge swipes in Windows 10](https://winaero.com/blog/how-to-disable-touchscreen-edge-swipes-in-windows-10/)

To modify the Registry, we could use the [Registry.SetValue Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registry.setvalue?view=netframework-4.8). To change the Group Policy, please refer [Changing Group Policy by C# coding](https://magicmao.wordpress.com/2011/08/05/changing-group-policy-by-c-coding/) or [using the IGroupPolicyObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2266797/how-to-apply-windows-group-policy-using-net)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion As far as I know, you can only activate this change by restarting the computer or logging out of the user account and logging in again. a solution is needed without these actions.